# Custom User model for Django with Facebook Login

Tags: django

On the client side I use the iOS SDK for Facebook to login and I get the Facebook ID and the access token.

Now on the Django side of things I would like to create a user with Facebook ID as the primary identifier and other fields like access token, first name, last name etc (the last two of which I will retrieve from the Graph API on the server side).

I know that I have to create a custom user model.

> If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a one-to-one relationship to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user.

This will not be enough as I will be using the Facebook ID and the access token for authentication.

This leaves me with two options: I can substitute a custom user model like so:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Or I can subclass AbstractUser:

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model and you just want to
>   add some additional profile information, you can simply subclass
>   django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and add your custom profile
>   fields.

But that doesn't sound quite right either. Also this design tip has confused me a little more.

> Model design considerations
>   Think carefully before handling information not directly related to authentication in your custom User Model.It may be better to store app-specific user information in a model that has a relation with the User model.

What is the best way to implement what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a side note: The problem of a custom user is that it is often the case that other apps (and yes, you will use them) don't interact correctly with it due to the assumptions they make on the base model for auth.

> This will not be enough as I will be using the Facebook ID and the access token for authentication.

I'm not sure you really need a custom user. For instance, I'm using [open id](https://github.com/simonw/django-openid) for authentication and there is no problem in using the default user: there is just another model with a OneToOne relationship to the default user.

The main concern you should have for a Facebook ID for authentication (and authentication in general) is to have a custom authentication Backend with its own specific facebook authentication.

Internally, [authenticate()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L43) runs through all installed backends (`settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`) and tries to authenticate the user with one of those.

You can search some of the existing implementations e.g. in [Django packages for facebook authentication](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/).

Comment: I was under the impression that using a OneToOne relationship would only help if the additional fields were just extra information and not fields required for authentication. I have looked into custom authentication backends, but I was first wondering how to setup my User model.

Comment: Yes, and my answer's message is that Facebook auth should be an extra authentication. Consider for instance the case where you are testing your website offline (with no web). You cannot authenticate to test it.

Comment: Extra authentication? So what would the minimum authentication be in my case?

Comment: Django's default (username+pass). You could even not allow normal users to authenticate this way (e.g. by setting a random 10-digit password). There are several reasons why default is good: other apps work out of the box; the auth system also controls staff/moderators; it is used in the contrib.admin, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your users should be enabled to login/register with username, mail and password -> use a `OneToOne` relationship to django's usermodel to store facebook credentials.

If your usermodel entirely depends on facebook data and you don't want your users to login with username/pass -> substitute the usermodel with `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`.

You might also want to take a look at [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) which solves much of your problems in a sweet little package.

Comment: I will not be requiring a password or a username because the user will be logging in via Facebook. So you would suggest an `AUTH_USER_MODEL` then?